# Why does pragma unroll 1 mean not unrolling at all?

Tags: c, pragma, loop-unrolling

If I have this code:

```
#pragma unroll 1
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   a[i]=i;
}
```

I read somewhere said `#pragma unroll 1` will prevent the compiler from unrolling the `for` loop. Why is that? And why does it not unroll the loop the first time, and run the for loop on the rest (ie `a[0]=0;` then run `for (i=1;i<5;i++)`)?

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: How would you unroll a loop 1 time? Based on your example I would say you're not sure what unrolling does. The examples here may help clarify things for you. Look at the unroll(3) example. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/opt_unroll.htm

Comment: I wasn't really familiar with pragma unroll, but with your particular loop, the absence of pragma, unroll 1 and unroll three compile identically on g++ 4.2.1 with default optimizations.

Comment: You can edit your own question, and fix the title, etc.  I've done it for you this time, but you should do it yourself in future.

Comment: Note that most pragmas are implementation specific.  The whole pragma feature was created specifically as an extension point, in fact, but modern C does define a handful of pragmas itself.  The key thing, though, is that we can only guess about what *your* `#pragma unroll 1` does or should do, unless you tell us which C implementation you're talking about.

Comment: For GCC, see [Using loop-specific pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html) — where it says _"The values of 0 and 1 block any unrolling of the loop"._  To the extent I understand it, `unroll 2` would mean embedding 2 iterations of the loop in a single cycle; `unroll 3` would mean embedding 3 iterations in a single cycle; so `unroll 1` is what happens with no unrolling, and `unroll 0` doesn't have a useful meaning so it is also deemed a no-op.